# How can I get options for filtering by a field directly from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to populate a filtering field based on the data I have indexed inside Elasticsearch. How can I retrieve this data? For example, my documents inside index "test" and type "doc" could be

```
{"id":1, "tag":"foo",  "name":"foothing"}
{"id":2, "tag":"bar",  "name":"barthing"}
{"id":3, "tag":"foo",  "name":"something"}
{"id":4, "tag":"quux", "name":"quuxthing"}
```

I'm looking for something like `GET /test/doc/_magic?q=tag` that would return `[foo,bar,quux]` from my data. I don't know what this is called or even possible. I don't want to get all index entries into memory and do this programmatically, I have  millions of documents in the index with around a hundred different tags.

Is this possible with ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible and this is called a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

You can do it like this:

```
GET /test/doc/_search
{   
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : { 
               "field" : "tag.keyword",
               "size": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that depending on the cardinality of your `tag` field, you can increase/decrease the `size` setting (10 by default).

Comment: Excellent, this looks like exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I do get the error `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default.` but that sounds like a minor configuration thing, I can google it.

Comment: can you try `tag.keyword` instead of `tag`?

Comment: Yes, that solves it 100%. Thank you very much indeed!